# jmeter setup thread group

Tags: testing, jmeter

My JMeter load test includes a setUp thread group that makes 190 http requests to my test environment prior to running my test thread groups. This results in a spike of requests at the beginning of the test that appear to be included in the results of the load test. The results for average throughput are higher than they would be without the setUp thread group traffic. Is there any way to exclude the setUp thread group from the test results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options:

1. [Synthesis Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213742/jmeter-setup-thread-group) plugin allows to set telemetry start and end offset values so you will be able to filter out unneeded data

   [image: Synthesis Report]
2. You can add Listener of your choice to 2nd Thread Group - it will record only samplers in its scope.

   [image: Aggregate Report]
3. You can run your JMeter tests via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool - the report will come in fancy web interface where you can zoom to the report part you need.

Answer (score 0):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss0cd.png]
If your recording catches extra "http requests" which are not required , Click on "Add Suggested Excludes" or else can exclude by defining , so that will not come in your Result Analysis.

Comment: unfortunately, many of the http requests in my setUp thread group are identical to requests in the actual test, so excluding by pattern isn't going to work. It seems obvious to me that users probably don't want requests in the setup and breakdown threads to be included in the test results. This should just be a checkbox at the thread level that says "Exclude this thread from test results"

Answer (score 0):

Which Listener/Reporter do you use to check your results? 
Some reporters can show you not only average throughput but also split it by requests or threads. So, you can rename your SetUp requests using one label and just exclude these values from your total. Don't know how to do it using built-in methods but you can easily export your result table data as a file or just operate it using scripting.

If you just want to prevent spike on your graph, then use Constant Throughput Timer for your SetUp thread. It will slow down your request sending (by increasing delays between them) to meet defined throughput.